# Passing complex parameters to `aws cloudformation deploy`

Tags: windows, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, localstack

From PowerShell I'm calling `aws cloudformation deploy` against LocalStack using a template generated by the CDK:

```
aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 cloudformation deploy --template-file ./cdk.out/my.template.json --stack-name my-stack --parameter-overrides functionLambdaSourceBucketNameParameter55F17A81=`{`"BucketName`":`"my-bucket`",`"ObjectKey`":`"code.zip`"`} functionLambdaSourceObjectKeyParameterB7223CBC=`{`"BucketName`":`"my-bucket`",`"ObjectKey`":`"code.zip`"`}
```

The code executes and I get a cryptic message back: `'Parameters'`. Also, the stack events show a failure but don't include any reason:

```
"ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
"Timestamp": "2020-09-24T19:03:28.388072+00:00",
"ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED"
```

I assume there is something wrong with the format of my parameters but I cannot find any examples of complex parameter values. The parameters are CodeParameters which have both BucketName and ObjectKey properties.

Comment: Can you check using real CloudFormation? This way you can check if this is localstack issue or CFN in general.